# Converter Stack Trace para String em JAVA

Tags: java, stack-trace

Qual seria a melhor maneira para converter o Stack Trace de uma `Exception` em `String`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me deparei com essa necessidade e fazendo um busca na web encontrei [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/how-can-i-convert-a-stack-trace-to-a-string) ótima solução no SOen, que permite obter essas importantes informações como `String`, sem ter a necessidade de importar outras bibliotecas:

```
try {
} catch (Exception e) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
    sw.toString(); //Aqui obtenho a String
}
```

Comment: Interessante, isso é muito util para fazer log em aplicações mais simples e pequenas, sem ter que ficar configurando libs externas e configurando recursos desnecessários.

Comment: Pois é, logo que utilizei, jé gerei um método estático pra fazer esse debug e outro para só armazenar os logs em arquivo estático...achei legal trazer pro SOpt também.

Comment: +1, [essa solução](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8521761/4056678) também parece boa.

Comment: Ótimo, poste aqui também @renan!